# How to write a value to existing dictionary that has nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I am trying to write a code that takes python script and convert it to `json`. So I am basically scraping the file and adding the required values to a dictionary that I have given below. There are multiple tasks where I need to write that to dictionary.

for line in new_data:

```
    if re.search(r'task_id=',line ):

        #write to dic['tasks'][0]['task_id'] 

(here there are multiple matches for task_id, so I have to iterate through the list and should be able to write to task_id)
```

I have already tried:

```py
dic['tasks'][0]['task_id'] = line.split(":")[1]
```

But it throws `list out of index error`. I don't get why it's throwing this error.

```py
dic = { 
    "tasks": [{
        "task_id": "1",
        "description": "Short Description.",
        "bitbucket_link": "",
        "can_restart": True,
        "cluster_size": "",
        "notes": ""
    }]
}
```

While the expected output should be:

```py
dic = { 
    "tasks": [{
        "task_id": "1",
        "description": "Short Description.",
        "bitbucket_link": "",
        "can_restart": True,
        "cluster_size": "",
        "notes": ""
    }, {
        "task_id": "2",
        "description": "Short Description.",
        "bitbucket_link": "",
        "can_restart": True,
        "cluster_size": "",
        "notes": ""
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you also add what is inside `developers` key? In the example you've given, I'm only seeing, what is inside `tasks` key! Do you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: The error means that `line` does not have a `:` in it. what is `line`?

Comment: Please add a snippet of the source dictionary. Without it, we can't help you. Also, you don't need to ask for help here, we already know. Take a look at the edits I made to your code to learn how to format code snippets better.

Comment: for line in new_data:
        if re.search(r'task_id=',line ):
            #write to dic['tasks'][0]['task_id']             (here there are multiple matches for task_id, so I have to iterate through the list and should be able to write to task_id)

Answer (score 0):

Check the type to make sure it's a dict. Index errors usually refer to lists.

```
print(type(my_dict))
```

Example that worked for me on a nested dict:

```
anomalies = apList[0]['vap_table'][0]['anomalies_bar_chart']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot @r1kchartrand. I am trying to write a new data into the nested dictionary, dic['tasks'][0]['task_id'] = line.split(":")[1] # line is the data in my file that I want to write to dictionary